# How to restrict password change in an active directory to a certain time period from "now"

Tags: active-directory, forgot-password

I couldn't come up with a better title, so here is what I'd like to do in an Active Directory (Windows 2008 R2):

A user forgot his password and asks an admin to set his password to a new, randomly generated password. Using this random password, the user logs in again and is prompted to change his password (via having the pwdLastSet option set to 0 when setting the random password).

So far, so good.

Is there a way to enforce that the new random password is only valid for a certain amount of time? The only idea I could come up with was to also set the accountExpires property to "now + n hours", but this poses the problem that I'd have to reset this property as soon as the user legitimatly changes his password within the given time frame, and I don't know how to do that.

Is this at all possible using Windows functionality?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a `PasswordExpire` date field for each password you can use that. if you don't have, i would recommend you create one.

if you don't want this kind of field you can create a database/file/any other way you choose that contains temporary passwords and their expire date/time

there are many other ways to do it. you need to decide the best for you and if you need help come to use with a problem, this is more a recommendation question.

Comment: I wanted to know whether there is a way to do it with AD mechanisms, so this seems to imply that there isn't.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger not that i know of, but i'm not an expert. maybe you should place a bounty....